# Am I taking the "true meaning" of "$\subset$" and in the context of this question to be wrong? Or the question is incorrect itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across this question in my assignment.

*Question 1.* **Let $A=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},1,\{1,\emptyset\},2\}$. Does the following hold true for the above set?**

$B=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{1,\emptyset \} \} \subset A$ **?** (It is told to be **true** in the soultions but I think it is not.)

I thought about it. Compared it with the set **A** but that took me nowhere. What I think is that it is **false** because...

*1. In order to be a subset of a set (**A** here), the "original elements" are taken out from the "original set" (again **A**) and are put into these $\{$  $\}$ which converts a respective element into a subset of the **set**.*

Now if I compare  **set A** and  the other **set B** (which I have to tell about if it holds true or not with respect to set **A**), I find...

*(A).   $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set so **B** should have $\emptyset$ contained in it. (Yes!)*

*(B). $\emptyset$ is taken out from **set A** and has been placed in **set B** so it should be in brackets. (yes it is!) like this $\{\emptyset\}$*

*(C). Coming to third and the last element of **set B** which is $\{1,\emptyset\}$, I find **1** when taken out from **set A** should simply have been placed like this $\{1\}$ but it is not rather it has been placed like this $\{1,\emptyset\}$ which I think is incorrect. (But soluions say it is **correct**, which I don't agree to).*

*(D). If they were have to be placed in **B** then I think there could have been a better way which is this...  $B=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{1\},\{\{\emptyset \}\} \} \subset A$ (True?) Or this $A=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},1,\{\{1,\emptyset\}\},2\}$ (True?)*

Am I correct in my approach? Also If you would like to suggest me something, go ahead.

Comment: For each element of $B$, see if it's an element of $A$. It's that simple.

Comment: What is the answer finally? I want to know this. Actually.

Comment: $B$ is a proper subset of $A$, so $B \subset A$.

Comment: You did not understand. Just answer this. Is it $true$ or $false$?

Comment: $B\subset A$ is true.

Comment: @Raffaele The case $B=\emptyset$ would be actually redudnant in that definition (and the $\Rightarrow$ would be syntactically wrong).

Comment: If we want to take out some elements from a **set A$=\{1,2,\{3,4\},5\}$  and write them as subset of set A** then won't each element come in brackets and then written as set B$=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$. Here is A $\subset$ B? Or to be a subset simply the subset should contain elements of the universal set and put them under initial and last bracket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $B$ has $3$ elements, namely
$$\emptyset,\;\;\{\emptyset\},\;\;\{1,\emptyset \}$$ 
The set $A$ has $5$ elements, namely
$$\emptyset,\;\;\{\emptyset\},\;\;1,\;\;\{1,\emptyset\},\;\;2$$
Since each element of $B$ is also an element of $A$, we have $B \subseteq A$.

But $B \ne A$, hence $B \subset A$.

Comment: By the way, for many authors $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ are interchangeable.

Comment: Right, but most modern texts (e.g., last $20$ years) appear to have chosen to $\subset$ to mean proper subset, so the notation is evolving.

Comment: The only potential trouble here is that if we're working in one of the (common!) developments of axiomatic set theory where $1=\{\varnothing\} $ and $2=\{1, \varnothing\} $, in which case $B=A$ and it then depends on notational convention whether we can say that $B\subset A$.

Comment: Agreed, but then that context would need to be specified. I'm assuming a more elementary context (e.g,, a first introduction to sets).

Comment: @quasi If we want to take out some elements from a **set A$=\{1,2,\{3,4\},5\}$  and write them as subset of set A** then won't each element come in brackets and then written as set B$=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$. Here is A $\subset$ B? Or to be a subset simply the subset should contain elements of the universal set and put them under initial and last bracket?

Comment: Elements are viewed as objects. There's no need to wrap them, and no need to look inside them. So the set $A=\{1,2,\{3,4\},5\}$
has $4$ elements, namely
$$1,\;\;2,\;\;\{3,4\},\;\;5$$
A subset $C$ of $A$ with elements $1,2$ would be written as $C=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: The set $B$ given by $B=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ has $2$ elements, namely
$$\{1\},\;\;\{2\}$$
but neither of those elements is an element of $A$. Thus, $B$ is _not_ a subset of $A$.

Comment: To clear up a potential confusion, consider the set 
$$S = \{1,2,3\}$$
Then:
$$$$
$1$ is an element of $S$, but $1$ is not a subset of $S$.
$$$$
$\{1\}$ is a subset of $S$, but $\{1\}$ is not an element of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

To check if $B$ is a subset of $A$, we can just check each element of $B$ individually, and see if each element of $B$ is also an element of $A$.

By the way, how many elements does $B$ have?  It has three elements.  And what are they?  Well, they are: $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}$, and $\{1,\emptyset\}$.

Let's check those three elements one by one.  We can start with $\{1,\emptyset\}$. Is this an element of $A$? The answer is yes. The set $A$ has five elements, and one of them is $\{ 1, \emptyset \}$.

You can check the other elements of $B$ similarly.

Comment: If we want to take out some elements from a **set A$=\{1,2,\{3,4\},5\}$  and write them as subset of set A** then won't each element come in brackets and then written as set B$=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$. Here is A $\subset$ B? Or to be a subset simply the subset should contain elements of the universal set and put them under initial and last bracket?